# R: increase value of element in vector 'a' by adding the value from another vector 'b' to the previous element in vector 'a'

Tags: r, vector

I have data for a time relevant response. The data is grouped by factors though the timestamp is not such that instead of having start time at 0ms for factor `a`, the start time is more like 1901ms and end time is 2801ms. Factor `b` then picks up where factor a ends and so forth. I subsetted the data by factor and calculated the difference between each data collected row for that group.

I would like to use the difference calculation to create a vector that starts at 0 and increases by adding the calculated difference stored in another vector.

For example if the difference vector looks like this:

```
difference_vector <- c(5, 2, 1, 6)
```

I need a new `timestamp` vector that looks like this:

```
timestamp <- c(0, 5(0+5), 7(5+2), 8(7+1), 14(8+6))
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `cumsum`:

```
> difference_vector <- c(5,2,1,6)
> timestamp <- c(0, cumsum(difference_vector))
> timestamp
[1]  0  5  7  8 14
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you! I am relatively new to R and admittingly unaware of all the amazing functions out there.

Comment: is there a way to do this by group so that the timestamp will start at 0 and then do the cumsum for every group?

Comment: If you can update the question with an example, I will try my best to help you